# Create flow by loadtest - msdn

Tags: c#, load-testing

I using on load test of Microsoft (I using on vs ultimate) ,
I want to create specific flow to run like this :

test1

test2

loop (test 3 - X% , test4 - Y% - randomly)

test5

I didn't see the option on load test framework to create it , this is support on execution of tests randomly without specific order .

Anyone know about solution for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost a standard facility in Visual Studio. If you combine test1 and test2 into a single test then you just use the standard built in mechanism.

In the test mix specify the combined test1plustest2 as "an initialize test to execute before other tests for each virtual user". Specify test5 as "a terminate test to execute after other tests for each virtual user". set test3 and test4 in the main test mix and set the percentages as required.

Comment: Thanks for your replay . I didn't see the option to set "an initialize test to execute..." in test mix :(